# How to override localparam? -GPARAM=VAL not working

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, questasim

I know we can override a generic/parameter in Verilog/SystemVerilog using vsim's option `-GMYPARAM=VALUE`.

This doesn't work for a `localparam` and the use of `localparam` in the module to prevent the change of the value isn't allowed.

```
mymod #(
  localparam A = 0  // not allowed
)(
...
);
```

Is there a way to override a localparam of a module or an instance from the tcl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the only way to override a `localparam` is by changing it to a `parameter`. But Modelsim has a `vopt` switch that global converts all localparam to parameters for the -G option. You can look it up in the ModelSim/Questa Reference Manual